# C# LINQ: Serialize nested collections to string with delimiters in single line of code

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, .net-3.5

I need to write a method that will do a regex match, and then return all matches and all groups (except for group 0, which is entire matched string) in every match in a single string, glued by two different delimiteres (one for mathes, one for groups).
I almost got it:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(
    "one=123 something two=5678 nothing three=90",
     @"([a-z]+)=(\d+)"
);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", 
    mc.OfType<Match>().SelectMany(m => 
        m.Groups.OfType<Group>().Select(g => 
            g.Value
        ).Skip(1)
    ).ToArray()));
```

This produces result: `one|123|two|567|three|90`, but what I need is: `one;123|two;567|three;90`

Problem is, that I don't know how to glue `GroupCollection` separately, that is, where and how to put another `string.Join()` (may be any other method of adding delimiter, ofcourse).

Please keep in mind, that I want to keep this syntax. I wouldn't be asking this question if I wanted to write two foreach loops :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it:

```
string.Join("|", 
    mc.OfType<Match>().Select(m => 
        string.Join(";",m.Groups.OfType<Group>().Select(g => 
            g.Value
        ).Skip(1).ToArray())
    ).ToArray()));
```

Now I know that `Select` and `SelectMany` work differently :).

Any answers with other approaches and explanations are still very welcome.

Comment: Looks good, so I'd keep it as is. I just want to add that doing things  in a single line of code shouldn't be a goal. Although it looks nice and clean, it complicates debugging since that is line based.

Comment: @MarkO You're right and I know that; the goal is to learn LINQ :).